# MySQL Update Table from File containing Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, io

I have a mysql table that looks like something like this:

```
----------------------
|   ID   |   Status  |
----------------------
|   0    | not ready |
|   1    | not ready |
|   2    | not ready |
|   3    | not ready |
|   4    | not ready |
|   5    | not ready |
|  ...   | not ready |
----------------------
```

And a file containing a list of IDs that looks like this:

```
0
1
13
24
133
...
```

I want to set `Status` in this table to `ready` at every ID listed in this file. Is there a way to do this from a bash script? preferably in one log on session. e.g. I don't want to do something like this:

```
for line in file: 
  mysql --user="me" --password="mypass" --database="db" --execute="exec this line"
```

which would have to log me in every time the line changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small list of IDs, use this:

```
mysql [options] --execute="UPDATE table SET Status='ready' WHERE ID IN (`paste -sd, id_file.txt`);"
```

For a larger set of IDs, reformat the file to contain both ID and Status fields, copy it to the server, and then use the LOAD INTO statement with the REPLACE option.